# How can classes with `std::variant` members be copied safely?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

The following sample builds and runs properly with the line `Container container2(container1);` removed. It appears the copy constructor for `std::variant` itself is deleted, which makes my `Container`'s copy constructor implicitly deleted.

Effectively, I'm asking:

1. What is the proper way to store a `std::variant` as a member?
2. What must be implemented in `Container` before safe copy/move assignment is allowed?

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class A {};

class Container {
 public:
  Container(int i) : data_(i) {}
  Container(float f) : data_(f) {}
  Container(std::string s) : data_(s) {}
  Container(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : data_(std::move(a)) {}
  std::variant<int, float, std::string, std::unique_ptr<A>> data_;
};

int main() {
  Container container1{3};
  
  // error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Container'
  // 
  // copy constructor of 'Container' is implicitly deleted because
  // field 'data_' has a deleted copy constructor
  Container container2(container1);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) has this to say about `std::variant`'s copy constructor:

> Copy constructor. [...] This constructor is defined as deleted unless `std::is_copy_constructible_v<T_i>` is true for all `T_i` in `Types`. [...]

In other words, it is *not* deleted unless one or more of the types that the `std::variant` can contain is not copyable for whatever reason.  In your case, it's the `std::unique_ptr` that's causing the problem.  Perhaps `std::shared_ptr` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Paul Sanders' answer: what kind of copy do you want?

If it is a shallow copy, use `shared_ptr<A>`.

If it is a deep copy, why not have `variant<..,A>`? If the reason is that `A` is polymorphic, then the real problem is cloning each of the derived classes. You have to create your own mechanism for the cloning and your own copyable smart pointer to use it - as far as I know, there is nothing in the standard library to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another addition to what you've already gotten: You need to implement the copying yourself since *no* `std::unique_ptr` is copyable.

> What must be implemented in `Container` before safe copy/move assignment is allowed?

For your specific case, where `A` is copy constructible and you'd like to support copying, it could look like this:

```
Container(const Container& rhs) {
    using namespace std; // to make the below less wide

    if(holds_alternative<int>(rhs.data_)) data_ = get<int>(rhs.data_);
    else if(holds_alternative<float>(rhs.data_)) data_ = get<float>(rhs.data_);
    else if(holds_alternative<string>(rhs.data_)) data_ = get<string>(rhs.data_);

    // this is the problematic one:

    else data_ = make_unique<A>( *get<unique_ptr<A>>(rhs.data_) );
}
```

`std::get` the pointer and dereference it (`*`) and let the copy constructor in `A` do its work.

There is no additional risk in doing this. Dereferencing the `unique_ptr` gets you an `A&` that you provide to `make_unique` which forwards that to the `A` being constructed. It's plain copying and there's no magic involved.

A slightly more complicated way could be to create your own `unique_ptr` wrapper that allows copying and use that in your `variant` instead.

Example:

```
template<typename T, typename D = std::default_delete<T>>
class copyable_obj_ptr {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    copyable_obj_ptr(Args&&... args) : ptr(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    
    // moving
    copyable_obj_ptr(copyable_obj_ptr&&) = default;
    copyable_obj_ptr& operator=(copyable_obj_ptr&&) = default;

    // copying
    copyable_obj_ptr(const copyable_obj_ptr& rhs) : ptr(new T(*rhs.ptr), D{}) {}
    copyable_obj_ptr& operator=(const copyable_obj_ptr& rhs) {
        ptr.reset(new T(*rhs.ptr));
        return *this;
    }

    // dereferencing
    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    T* operator->() { return ptr.get(); }
    const T& operator->() const { return ptr.get(); }

    // Add more proxy methods to access the unique_ptr's methods if you need them ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T, D> ptr;
};
```

Comment: And when he copies the contained `std::unique_ptr` that way what do you suppose happens now that _two_ unique ptrs think they own the same heap-allocated object?

Comment: I don't agree that it is useful. If you want to just copy A like this, include in `variant` instead of `unique_ptr<a>`. And if for whatever reason you need a ptr, it is easier to create a copying ptr class than implement this logic for `Container`.

Comment: No `unique_ptr` is copied. The _object_ it points at is - and if that is _not_ a valid case, the copy constructor should be left `delete`d and OP:s question would be sort of pointless.

Comment: I see.  Well, if that is in fact useful to the OP.  But - it certainly isn't the usual case that a unique ptr points to an object that doesn't have identity.

Comment: @davidbak It's very useful. I've implemented copy constructors in small classes holding a resource with a `unique_ptr`. If the object it points at - fine. There are reasons why a `unqiue_ptr` doesn't do this automatically but providing copying is by no means _bad_.

Comment: @davidbak Yes, the mechansm works, so if you downvoted the answer for this reason, it is not right. But if somebody else did not downvote, I would downvote it because it is a wrong design.

Comment: @Eugene I've got two objections. 1) I'm answering a question. Not designing. 2) I don't agree that it's bad design per default. Using a `unique_ptr` for a resource helps you and lets you only focus on the copying part. If the resource **is** copyable and you'd like to support that - just go ahead and implement it.

Comment: I'd like to hear the reason for the downvote though. I may have missed something that makes my answer not useful.